# Dataframe get exact value using an array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
        A   B   C   D   Count
0   0   0   0   0   12.0
1   0   0   0   1   2.0
2   0   0   1   0   4.0
3   0   0   1   1   0.0
4   0   1   0   0   3.0
5   0   1   1   0   0.0
6   1   0   0   0   7.0
7   1   0   0   1   9.0
8   1   0   1   0   0.0
... (truncated for readability)
```

And an array: `[1, 0, 0, 1]`

I would like to access `Count` value given the above values of each column. In this case, this would be `row 7` with Count = 9.0

I can use iloc or at by deconstructing each value in the array, but that seems inefficient. Wondering if there's a way to map the values in the array to a value of a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `tuple`

```
out = df.loc[df[list('ABCD')].apply(tuple,1) == (1, 0, 0, 1),'Count']
Out[333]: 
7    9.0
Name: Count, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I chose this one to implement as I needed to update `Count` after

Answer (score 3):

You can index the DataFrame with a list of the key column names and compare the resulting view to the array, using NumPy broadcasting to do it for each line at once. Then collapse the resulting Boolean DataFrame to a Boolean row index with `all()` and use that to index the Count column.

If `df` is the DataFrame and `a` is the array (or a list):

```py
df.Count.loc[(df[list('ABCD')] == a).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I really like how readable this answer is.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the `.loc` command, and searched for the multiple conditions like this:

```py
f = [1,0,0,1]
result = df['Count'].loc[(df['A']==f[0]) & 
                         (df['B']==f[1]) & 
                         (df['C']==f[2]) & 
                         (df['D']==f[3])].values
print(result)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[9.]
```

However, I like Arne's answer better :)